# jQuery Automatic page scroll with HTML slider to control animation speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroller

I've been looking around and I think I'm fairly close to getting this but when I move my slider to alter the speed of the animation, nothing seems to happen. I'm assuming this has something to do with the animation already in progress? Here's the code I have thus far:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.10.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function pageScroll(speed)
{
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, speed);    
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<body onLoad="pageScroll(100000);">

<input onChange="pageScroll(this.value);" type="range" value="100000" name="slider" min="0" max="200000"  style="position:fixed; left:0;top:0">

<center><img src="page-0.jpg" width="800">
<img src="page-1.jpg" width="800">
<img src="page-2.jpg" width="800">
<img src="page-3.jpg" width="800"></center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you got two <body> tags, just fyi

Answer (score 0):

Please delete these Part of your code `<body onLoad="pageScroll(100000);">`

And you have 2 body tags in your code... It's not good...

If you want to do something, when your page is loaded, then do it in JS with helps of jQuery ->

```
$(function() {
    /* things to do, after the page is loaded */
    pageScroll(100000);
});
```

To change the animation, use .stop(). It breaks all animations in queues. For more information, read [API docs](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
function pageScroll(speed) {
    $("html,body").stop().animate({ scrollTop: 119}, 500 );
}
```

And i'm not sure, but i think i had some Problem with this selector... if it doesn't work, try this selector:

```
$("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ASMITH/AECva/

```
<input id="slider" type="range" value="10000" name="slider" min="100" max="20000"     style="position:fixed; left:0;top:0"></input>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var vHeight = $('body').height();
$('#slider').change(function () {
    var speed = $('#slider').val();
    $('body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: vHeight
    }, +speed);
});
```

});

Comment: Actually I think I got it working as I'd like except it doesn't scroll to the bottom of the page on all of my pages (sometimes stops about half way through).

Comment: if you get the height of the page using: 'var vHeight = $('body').height();' and set that as the scrollTop value it should always go down to the bottom of the page.